# cant use latex in slader site to draw geometry shapes

Tags: draw, shapes

i use slader site which use latex to answer math question but i can't draw geometric axies nor electric diagrams, i tried to type some solution from stackExchange but it did't work can some one help me

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) As this seems to be about an external site I fear that this question is off topic here. The tag `{geometry}` is surely wrong since it is a _package_ to handle page margins.

Comment: What is "slader site"?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I think you should contact the site support to figure out what they allow with regard to TikZ and similar packages.

Answer (score 2):

I work for Slader as well (I am one of their moderators).

I would recommend to use Geogebra or Desmos to create geometric axes, because a lot of LaTeX packages are not implemented in the LaTeX editor used by the website (only the most used packages and commands have been implemented). I personally prefer to use Geogebra, which is also a lot quicker than using LaTeX.

Similarly, you could use a third-party tool to create electric diagrams. For example, iCircuit could be used (but you have to pay for this technology).

I hope this helps!

Kind Regards, 
Sarah Schrijvers